# Wake on LAN for Microsoft Security Essentials?

Tags: windows-7, apple, wake-on-lan, bootcamp, mac

Is it possible to have an iMac (running Windows 7 via BootCamp) to Wake on LAN overnight and run a Microsoft Security Essentials scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

iMac's support WoL, and when they're running Windows they're just like any other EUFI-based PC, so yes you can.